# Device info using KQL

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-data-explorer, kql

How can we get a device info using KQL, Is there any inbuilt function in Azure ?

I have checked but am not able to find out. Can anyone help me out of this ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking at the application insights logs from the invocation logs then you can use `Cloud_RoleName` for the name of the function app (the app service itself) and `operation_name` for the function name. In the following example I have a function called `MyFunction` that is run from the app service `MyFunctionApp`.

```
requests
| project timestamp, id, operation_Name, success, resultCode, duration, operation_Id, cloud_RoleName, invocationId=customDimensions['InvocationId']
| where timestamp > ago(30d)
| where cloud_RoleName =~ 'MyFunctionApp' and operation_Name =~ 'MyFunction'
| order by timestamp desc
| take 20
```

Comment: Am able to get the info but i see lot of client model as 'other' in result.